# Kotlin/Native Basic Image manipulation

Tags: kotlin, image-processing, kotlin-native

Does Kotlin/Native  support any image-processing libraries? 
(I'm targeting Windows & Linux)

I failed to find anything on google that doesn't target JVM/Android, but I am new to the Kotlin ecosystem so the answer might be right under my nose.

I'm looking for basic manipulations:

- open/save image(jpg, png)
- resize
- extract crop

If there aren't any, should I try to create bindings for C Image processing library like  [stb-image](https://github.com/nothings/stb) or opencv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [korim](https://github.com/korlibs/korim) library, that might help you. Also, there are several places you can find more info on Kotlin/Native libraries, like [here](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries) and [here](https://kotlin.link). 
 The option with C library seems also like a good idea. If you'll got some problems with it, feel free to ask here on in Kotlin Slack ([get an invite here](http://slack.kotlinlang.org/?_ga=2.37612768.1502458466.1580712992-1194240550.1578557352)).